# User last_value to fill dates

Tags: oracle

I have the following table.

```
MY_DAY      | STMT_DATE
------------+-------------
12/31/2013  | 12/31/2013
1/1/2014    | 
1/2/2014    | 1/2/2014
1/3/2014    | 1/3/2014
1/4/2014    | 
1/5/2014    | 
1/6/2014    | 1/6/2014
1/7/2014    | 1/7/2014
1/8/2014    | 1/8/2014
1/9/2014    | 1/9/2014
1/10/2014   | 1/10/2014
1/11/2014   | 
1/12/2014   | 
1/13/2014   | 1/13/2014
1/14/2014   | 1/14/2014
```

and I would like to get  for each row the previous and following non-null value for STMT_DATE. I'm using the following query:

```
      SELECT my_day,
         stmt_date,
         first_VALUE (stmt_date IGNORE NULLS) OVER (ORDER BY stmt_date asc ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING) previous,
         first_VALUE (stmt_date IGNORE NULLS) OVER (ORDER BY stmt_date desc ROWS BETWEEN 1 FOLLOWING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING)  next
    FROM DATE_TEST
ORDER BY my_day
```

But I'm getting the following results:

```
MY_DAY     | STMT_DATE  | PREVIOUS   | NEXT
-----------+------------+------------+--------------
12/31/2013 | 12/31/2013 |            | 
1/1/2014   |            | 12/31/2013 | 1/14/2014
1/2/2014   | 1/2/2014   | 12/31/2013 | 12/31/2013
1/3/2014   | 1/3/2014   | 12/31/2013 | 1/2/2014
1/4/2014   |            | 12/31/2013 | 1/14/2014
1/5/2014   |            | 12/31/2013 | 1/14/2014
1/6/2014   | 1/6/2014   | 12/31/2013 | 1/3/2014
1/7/2014   | 1/7/2014   | 12/31/2013 | 1/6/2014
1/8/2014   | 1/8/2014   | 12/31/2013 | 1/7/2014
1/9/2014   | 1/9/2014   | 12/31/2013 | 1/8/2014
1/10/2014  | 1/10/2014  | 12/31/2013 | 1/9/2014
1/11/2014  |            | 12/31/2013 | 1/14/2014
1/12/2014  |            | 12/31/2013 | 1/14/2014
1/13/2014  | 1/13/2014  | 12/31/2013 | 1/10/2014
1/14/2014  | 1/14/2014  | 12/31/2013 | 1/13/2014
```

Any suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using functions `lag()` and `lead()` we have somewhat shorter syntax:

```
select my_day, stmt_date,
    lag(stmt_date ignore nulls) over (order by my_day) previous,
    lead(stmt_date ignore nulls) over (order by my_day) next
  from date_test 
  order by my_day
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/980ef/1)

Answer (score 1):

After some work, I have the answer to your question.

```
SELECT 
   my_day,
   stmt_date,
   LAST_VALUE (stmt_date IGNORE NULLS) OVER (ORDER BY my_day, stmt_date desc ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING) Previous,
   FIRST_VALUE (stmt_date IGNORE NULLS) OVER (ORDER BY my_day, stmt_date desc ROWS BETWEEN 1 FOLLOWING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) Next
FROM 
   DATE_TEST
ORDER BY 
   my_day;
```

Here you have a working example
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f2fec/38

Hope this helps